# How to use a C# app with a database on any PC

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, local-database

Is there any way to create a C# app with a database in order to move it on any PC and work without internet connection?

I have had a lot of problems moving my setup on other PCs - evrything is lost from the database when I first run on another PC.

Thank you! And sorry if it is a dumb question I am really new.

Comment: Which database are you using? You should re-create/or restore backup of the database on another system when you use your app on another system. Or you can use SQLite if your db is not so big.

Comment: I`m using Service-based Database from Visual Studio Community 2015.I have no idea how to backup a database

Comment: Is it a desktop app or a web app?

Comment: @Shaharyar  desktop app

Comment: You need to consider all features of a RDBMS not just portability of data. Almost all databases can be backed up and reloaded. Also, you may want to consider placing your db on a server. Don't let setting up data in the database be the driver for your RDBMS choice.

Comment: @Shaharyar I looked for backup and restoring .. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/873677/SQL-Server-Database-Backup-and-Restore-in-Csharp .. this is what I have to do? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Macpp That is what I said. Post it as answer, and accept it. It will help others too in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the sqlite database. It's like MySQL but uses files. The library is free and there are many viewers. For small database it's the best and also it's very easy to install and to use.

Answer (score 0):

So, thank you all! I found the answer. I have to create a backup of database and restore when i change the system. Here is a link :  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/873677/SQL-Server-Database-Backup-and-Restore-in-Csharp